# Laravel 5 helper function asset different domains

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.0, I am using the helper function asset to show where different assets are ( css, js images etc. ). I am building a platform that shows different information depending on the url which means I cannot bind the asset to a url. I know in config/app.php it has 'url' => 'http://localhost' but I cannot change that because the url will not always be the same. Is there a way to set this up to handle the domain changing within the same application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your assets are always going to be in the same relative path from the root of the site (regardless of the domain), you should just be able to output the URL to various assets as a relative URL. So, for example, if in your blade template you had something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/style.css') !!}">
```

you could replace it with a relative URL like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css">
```

This should resolve correctly regardless of what domain you're on, and should also be fetched via HTTPS in the case that the user is on a secure page.

If you need something more complicated, you might consider setting a `session('domain')` variable or something that would be accessible from a global scope that could then be used to generate links to assets like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://{{ session('domain') }}/assets/css/style.css">
```

If none of these work, then your situation is probably complicated enough that you'll need to provide us some more code before we can offer workable solutions.